# Problemas al implementar varios Logros de Google Games en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

He programado varios logros en Google Games, y a a la hora de implementarlos, si solo pongo uno no hay problema, si pongo los 5 al llegar al numero se hace lento el juego y te hace perderlo.
después del código donde suma el score:

```
                    if (score > 40) {

                        Games.Achievements
                                .unlock( getApiClient(),
                                        getString( R.string.achievement_acornbull ) );



                    }
                    if (score > 90) {
                        Games.Achievements
                                .unlock( getApiClient(),
                                        getString( R.string.achievement_elastic_spring ) );

                        

                        //game_paused = true;
                        //anim_hero.stop();
                    }

                    if (score > 200) {
                        Games.Achievements
                                .unlock( getApiClient(),
                                        getString( R.string.achievement_bronze_medal ) );


                    }
                    if (score > 500) {

                        Games.Achievements
                                .unlock( getApiClient(),
                                        getString( R.string.achievement_silver_medal ) );

                    }

                    if (score > 900) {
                        Games.Achievements
                                .unlock( getApiClient(),
                                        getString( R.string.achievement_gold_medal ) );

                    }



                }
```

cuando llegas a 40 puntos, y no tienes el logro, se ve la notificación, pero se hace lento igual y pierdes la partida. el logro se te graba correcto en tu Google Games,
si llegas a 40, y ya tienes el logro, no sale notificación(normal), pero se hace lento igual.
he mirado todas las formas posibles. alguna ayuda que me aclare? gracias

Answer (score 0):

Vale, ya esta solucionado.. no he encontrado nada sobre esto, en la pagina de desarrolladores de google, te indica como insertar un logo, pero nadie habla de como hacerlo para varios,sin el problema detallado, pero a base de prueba error lo conseguí por mis propios medios y funciona a la perfección. Gracias ;)